# What is the purpose of passing-in undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I have noticed `jQuery` and related keynote plugins like `jQuery.UI` pass `undefined` as a parameter into anonymous functions used in their module definitions, like so:

```
(function($, undefined) { ... })(jQuery);
```

Alternatively, I have noticed other plugins recommended by jQuery and/or others do NOT pass undefined in as a parameter.

This is probably a silly question, but...

Shouldn't it always be available anyway?  Why pass it in?  Is there some sort of other purpose or trick going on here?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

There are two reasons for that:

1) If `undefined` is a variable in the function scope rather than a global object property, minifiers can reduce it to a single letter thus achieving a better compression rate.

2) Before ES5*, `undefined` was a property of the global object without write-protection. So it could be overwritten, resulting in strange and unexpected behavior. You could do something like this:

```
var test = 123;
undefined = 123;
if (test === undefined){
   // this will actually be true, since undefined now equals 123
}
```

By having an function argument `undefined` (the name actually does not matter) which you don't pass a parameter to, you could make sure you have a variable which really is `undefined` so you can test "undefinedness" against this variable.

Btw. the safest method to test for undefined is: `typeof ( var ) === 'undefined'`

(*) With EcmaScript 5, the global properties `undefined`, `NaN` and `Infinity` became readonly. So with its general adoption in all modern browsers - of course with the exception of IE 9 - overwriting those values was not possible anymore.

Comment: The reason jQuery uses this method instead of `typeof` is that it compresses much better in a Javascript minifier.

Comment: Thats true, nonetheless typeof is the safest method. You also could use the falsy nature of undefined, which would be the shortest check for `undefined` but is shadowed by the existence of other falsy values.

Answer (score 17):

That is done to make sure that undefined always is `undefined`. In older versions of the ECMAScript spec (prior to ECMAScript 5),  undefined wasn't a reserved word but a regular variable. In older browsers this would be allowed for instance:

```
undefined = 2; // Assign a different value to undefined

// Now this statement would be true
if (undefined == 2)
```

So to make sure that undefined is in fact undefined, even if some other "evil" script would have reassigned undefined with another value, you create a parameter that you call undefined, and then when you call the function, you make sure to not pass a value to that parameter - thus you can be sure that the variable undefined will always be undefined within your function.

So in the case of jQuery:

```
(function($, undefined) { ... })(jQuery);
```

They pass in jQuery and assign it to the $ variable for convenience, but then they don't pass a second value to the undefined parameter, thus undefined will be undefined.

**Modern browsers**

In modern browsers, `undefined` is a non-configurable, non-writable property per the [ECMAScript 5 specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1.1.3).

Answer (score 10):

undefined is not a reserved word in javascript, it is simply a variable. jQuery is ensuring that if some bad developer overwrites the value of undefined in their javascript, then jQuery will ignore it and establish it's own variable, undefined, which is never passed a value (see the self-executing (jQuery) at the end) and is therefore actually undefined.