# Self-invoking function and params?

Tags: javascript, function, identifier

I've seen the next way of writing self-invoking functions:

```
(function (app) {
    app.foo = {
        bar: function(){}
    };
}(App));
```

Where `App` is a global object.

I wonder, why do we need to pass `App` as a param into a function? Why don't just use this:

```
(function () {
    App.foo = {
        bar: function(){}
    };
}());
```

I see only one advantage of using the first way. If we for some reason rename the `App` object, then we can easily rename the param in brackets and our code will work as it works. But in case of the second way we will probably need to rename `App` in all places where we use it.

Are there other differences?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It means that the contents of the function – with regards to the `app` identifier – are agnostic to the global (or parent) scope.

One of the scenarios in which this is done is, for example, with jQuery, when you don't want to assume that the jQuery object is called `$` (e.g. if no-conflict mode is on), but you *do* want to call it by that name. Passing it through an anonymous function like this (i.e. `(function($) {})(jQuery)`) allows you to generate a locally-scoped alias that doesn't interfere with the external meaning of the name `$` in the parent/global scope.

Answer (score 2):

The other answers explain the benefit of having a locally scoped copy. There are a few other benefits too:

- As a micro-optimization it reduces scope lookups (it's less expensive to find a local var than a global one).
- It can help in the minification process as all your params are reduce to single letter named vars.
- It gives you a pseudo dependency management technique...in your example, you know your code is dependent on `App`.

Answer (score 1):

For example, many libraries use the "$" character as a shortcut for their main function (e.g. JQuery). This is convenient, but can cause a clash when using multiple libraries. So, you could pass `JQuery` in like this:

```
(function($) {
    // Code
    var nav = $('#nav');
    // More code
})(JQuery);
```

That way, you can still use the convenient shortcut, but you can also avoid clashes (as long as you also configure the libraries not to use the "$" shortcut).

Answer (score 1):

You can also use it to redefine global variables locally to ensure they contain whay you expect:

```
(function($, undefined) { ... })(jQuery);
```

Where `undefined` is now the expected undefined. Also see: [What is the purpose of passing-in undefined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602901/what-is-the-purpose-of-passing-in-undefined)

Most other uses are well covered in the other answers.