# what's the purpose of `new Function("return this")()` in immediately invoked function

Tags: javascript

I'm reviewing the [setImmediate polyfill](https://github.com/YuzuJS/setImmediate/blob/master/setImmediate.js#L175) and it's wrapped inside immediate-invoking function with the following:

```
(function (global, undefined) {
    "use strict";
...
}(new Function("return this")()));
```

I'm confused about the purpose the last statement and the parameters being passed to the function. Does it have something to do that this code might be run inside a browser as well as on Node.js? Can you please clarify?

Comment: It means the method will return the object it belongs to.

Comment: *"Does it have something to do that this code might be run inside a browser as well as on Node.js? "* Seems like it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The code is written so it has access to the global scope, *without having to know what the object containing that scope is*.  For instance in a browser the global scope is `window`, but in other containers that is not the case.

By using the [Function constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function), you get direct access to the global scope:

> Note: Functions created with the Function constructor do not create
>   closures to their creation contexts; they always are created in the
>   global scope. When running them, they will only be able to access
>   their own local variables and global ones, not the ones from the scope
>   in which the Function constructor was called. This is different from
>   using eval with code for a function expression.

So by doing:

```
(new Function("return this")())
```

You create and invoke a new function on the global scope, that returns whatever that global scope is.  This is then immediately passed to the main function as the `global` object.

Comment: thanks, I see. What's the point of also passing `undefined` to the function?

Comment: @Maximus A couple of reasons, best addressed in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9602975/791010)

Comment: *"This is different from using eval with code for a function expression."* I wonder if an **indirect** eval call would have the same effect. I.e. `(0, eval)('this')`. Would be a bit shorter.

Comment: @FelixKling You mean something like `(0, eval).call(this,'this')`?

Comment: @JamesThorpe: `.call` doesn't seem to be necessary to create an indirect call (that's what the `(0, eval)` is for), but yes.

Comment: @FelixKling right.  I need to study those short blocks a little more to fully get them yet.

Answer (score 8):

In non-strict mode, when a function is called without setting the `this` value, it will become the global object:

> [**10.4.3 Entering Function Code**](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.4.3)
>
> 1. If the function code is strict code, set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to *thisArg*.
> 2. Else if *thisArg* is **null** or **undefined**, set the [ThisBinding](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-10.3) to the
>      global object.

Therefore, the [`this` keyword](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.1.1) may be way to obtain a reference to the [global object](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.1):

```
this; // the global object
```

The first problem is that `this` could have been customized (e.g. with [`apply`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.3) or [`call`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.4.4)):

```
(function() {
    this; // `123`, not the global object!
}).call(123);
```

This can be easily fixed using a self-executing function:

```js
// `this` may not be the global object here
(function() {
    this; // the global object
})();
```

But there is a more serious problem: `this` doesn't become the global object in strict mode:

```js
'use strict';
(function() {
    this; // `undefined`, not the global object!
})();
```

To fix that, you can use a [Function Constructor](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.3.2). Even inside strict mode, the new function will be non-strict by default.

```
'use strict';
(function() {
    new Function("return this")(); // the global object
})();
```

Answer (score -1):

get the global object whatever the js runtime is;(eg node, browser and so on);