# What is the difference between `Function('return this')` and `function() {return this}`?

Tags: javascript

In a lot of the compiled Javascript modules, somewhere in the preamble there is an invocation to `Function('return this')()` to get the global object. I'm working in an interpreter environment where the use of `Function` constructor (along with `eval`) is forbidden for security reasons. I replaced the above code with `(function(){return this})()` and everything seems to be working.

Is this a safe substitution to do? Are there cases where it would fail? Why do most compiled JS modules prefer the constructor version anyway?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29706284/whats-the-purpose-of-new-functionreturn-this-in-immediately-invoked-fun - Doesn't give you a complete answer but there's some good information there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode#Securing_JavaScript) you don't get the global object; you get `undefined` instead:

```js
console.log( window === function(){
  return (function(){return this})();
}() ); // true

console.log( window === function(){
  "use strict";
  return (function(){return this})();
}() ); // false
```

The Function constructor escapes strict mode, so that you get the same result regardless of whether you're already in strict mode:

```js
console.log( window === function(){
  return Function('return this')();
}() ); // true

console.log( window === function(){
  "use strict";
  return Function('return this')();
}() ); // true
```

Answer (score 0):

In your first case `Function('return this')()` is declared in a global scope and in a non-strict mode if that function is called without setting the this value `this` will be linked to the global object.

In your second case `(function(){return this})()` you are creating Immediately Invoked Function Expressions.